# error select in select query on codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. When i use this query

```
$last_insert_id =$this->db->insert_id();
    $name = 'Auto loan';
    $q = $this->db->select('id')->where('name_of_loan',$name)->limit(1)->get('loan_type');

$data_batch = array(
'borrower_id' => $last_insert_id,
'loan_type_id'=> $q,

);
//$this->db->set('loan_type_id', $query);
$this->db->set('created_on', 'NOW()', FALSE);
$this->db->set('updated_on', 'NOW()', FALSE);
$this->db->insert('loan_application',$data_batch);
```

I get the following error :
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: please follow this --  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-benefit-of-using-query-on-Codeigniter-format-than-normal-SQL-format

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$last_insert_id =$this->db->insert_id();
$name = 'Auto loan';
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM loan_type WHERE name_of_loan = '$name' ");
$result = $query->result_array();
$q = $result[0]['id'];

$data_batch = array(
    'borrower_id' => $last_insert_id,
    'loan_type_id'=> $q,        
);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a framework then you have to follow framework syntax above answered is correct but it`s answered in core php format not in framework format if you will use core concept then why you are using framework leave it and use this query for select data --

```
     $name = 'Auto loan';
     $this->db->select('id');
     $this->db->from('loan_type');
     $this->db->where('name_of_loan',$name);
     $this->db->limit(1);
     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query->result_array();
```

Please Try This.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623594/error-select-in-select-query-on-codeigniter#comment55021335_33623660) and that's also **CI Define method**

Comment: yes it will work fine but ci has also provide by defaults methods for fetching data, inserting data then why we neglect them ?

Comment: There is no performance drop or any other harm. Which way is best you can use that

Comment: how can say that. there is no harm ?

Comment: @Abdulla Please read this --
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-benefit-of-using-query-on-Codeigniter-format-than-normal-SQL-format

Comment: You read [this](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#regular-queries)

Comment: yes but here we will need to escape the data..for preventing sql injection attacks if we didn`t use esacpe method according to you then it can harmful to our data but by using by default ci methods we didn`t need any escapse method because it`s already added internally escapse method

Comment: why i will do it for insert data according to you --  $sql = "INSERT INTO table (title) VALUES(".$this->db->escape($title).")";

Comment: SQL attacks prevented in `$this->input->post`.  ***Not in query.***

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94674/discussion-between-sorav-garg-and-abdulla).

Answer (score 0):

if i want to insert data like that --

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO create_shop (shop_name,shop_category,address,location,city,state,postal_code,phone_no,email,min_ammount,description,user_id,image1,image2,image3,image4,date_time)
                VALUES(" . $this->db->escape($this->input->post('shop_name')) . "
                        ," . $this->db->escape($this->input->post('shop_category')) . "
                        ," . $this->db->escape($this->input->post('address')) . "
                        ," . $this->db->escape($this->input->post('location')) . "
                        ," . $this->db->escape($this->input->post('city')) . "
                        ," . $this->db->escape($this->input->post('state')) . "
                        ," . $this->db->escape($this->input->post('postal_code')) . "
                        ," . $this->db->escape($this->input->post('phone_no')) . "
                        ," . $this->db->escape($this->input->post('email')) . "
                        ," . $this->db->escape($this->input->post('min_ammount')) . "
                        ," . $this->db->escape($this->input->post('description')) . "
                        ,".$this->db->escape($this->session->userdata('username'))."
                        ,".$this->db->escape($f_newfile)."
                        ,".$this->db->escape($f_newfile1)."
                        ,".$this->db->escape($f_newfile2)."
                        ,".$this->db->escape($f_newfile3)."
                        ," . $this->db->escape($now) . ")";
```

then according this it will be very long code but by usng ci methods we can do 
it in a single line -- `$this->db->insert('table_name',$data);`